# Can someone guide me through the proof for this? Combining inverse functions and intersection is confusing me

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let *f* be a function that maps X into Y (*f*: X $\to$Y). Let {$G_\alpha$| $\alpha$ $\in$ A} be an indexed family of subsets of Y. 
 Show *f*$^{-1}$ $\bigl($$\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}$ G$_\alpha$ $\bigl)$ = $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}$ *f* $^{-1}$ $\bigl(G_\alpha\bigl)$

Comment: The usual approach is to show the left-hand side is a subset of the right-hand side, and vice versa. Have you tried this, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Here $f^{-1}$ is the *preimage* operation, not an inverse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you proof the simpler version for finite intersections?

$f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$.

The general version is just a slight variation of this proof.

We have to proof equality of sets.
For that we proof $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.

To proof "$\supseteq$", we take $x\in f^{-1}(A\cap B)=\text{recall definition of $f^{-1}(\text{set})$}$. We have to show that $x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$

What can you conclude?
All you have to do is basically that you write carefully down how the 'signs' are defined.  There are no tricks involved.

Then "$\supseteq$" is proved similarly, or you can just 'reverse' your proof of $\subseteq$.

Once you finished this proof, the other one should be problem.

Give it a try, and feel free to ask if you get stuck.